# Mutate function in dplyr not working with Rolling Means/ Moving Averages

Tags: r, dplyr, zoo

First and foremost, regardless if you have input or not, thank you for taking your time to view my question.

Let me break down what I am doing, the sample dataset, and the error.

What I currently have is data for several different ID's that list the dispersion per day. (you will see below). I want to loop through the dates and add two columns to the data : **Rolling Means columns & Rolling standard deviation column**.

The code I have written out so far is this:

```
library(zoo)
Testing1 <- function(dataset, k) {
ops <- data.frame()  
for (i in unique(dataset$Date)) {  
ops <- dataset %>% mutate(rolling_mean = rollmean(dataset$Dispersion,k)) %>% 
mutate(rolling_std = rollapply(dataset$Dispersion, width = k, FUN = sd))
}
Results <<- ops 
}
```

however, i get the following error:

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
>     Column `rolling_mean` must be length 30 (the number of rows) or one, not 26

I am assuming that the row differential is due to me specifying a 5 day window for the rolling average, meaning it won't calculate it for the first 4 rows. But how do I go about telling R that it's ok to input NA's on those rows? Or If you guys have any other solution, that would work as well. Please do help.

Heres a sample of the data:

```
Identifier  Date    Dispersion
1000    2/15/2018   0.390
1000    2/16/2018   0.664
1000    2/17/2018   0.526
1000    2/18/2018   0.933
1000    2/19/2018   0.009
1000    2/20/2018   0.987
1000    2/21/2018   0.517
1000    2/22/2018   0.641
1000    2/23/2018   0.777
1000    2/24/2018   0.613
1001    2/15/2018   0.617
1001    2/16/2018   0.234
1001    2/17/2018   0.303
1001    2/18/2018   0.796
1001    2/19/2018   0.359
1001    2/20/2018   0.840
1001    2/21/2018   0.291
1001    2/22/2018   0.699
1001    2/23/2018   0.882
1001    2/24/2018   0.467
1002    2/15/2018   0.042
1002    2/16/2018   0.906
1002    2/17/2018   0.077
1002    2/18/2018   0.156
1002    2/19/2018   0.350
1002    2/20/2018   0.060
1002    2/21/2018   0.457
1002    2/22/2018   0.770
1002    2/23/2018   0.433
1002    2/24/2018   0.366
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this error because the length of rolling means/stds does not match the legth of *Dispersion*. Simply add **k - 1** `NA`s at the beginnig of your means/stds vectors.

Below is a working example. You can modify this based on your needs.

```
my_function <- function(df, k) {
  df %>%
    mutate(
      rolling_mean = c(rep(NA, k - 1), rollmean(Dispersion, k)),
      rolling_std = c(rep(NA, k - 1), rollapply(Dispersion, width = k, FUN = sd))
    )
}
```

For example, you may want to add `group_by` to compute these values for each *Identifier*:

```
my_function <- function(df, k) {
  df %>%
    group_by(Identifier) %>%
    mutate(
      rolling_mean = c(rep(NA, k - 1), rollmean(Dispersion, k)),
      rolling_std = c(rep(NA, k - 1), rollapply(Dispersion, width = k, FUN = sd))
    )
}
```

**Update following up @G. Grothendieck's comment:**

It turns out the package `zoo` already has comprehensive features for `NA` handling, refactoring the above-given code as:

```
my_function <- function(df, k) {
  df %>%
    mutate(
      rolling_mean = rollmeanr(Dispersion, k, fill = NA),
      rolling_std = rollapplyr(Dispersion, width = k, FUN = sd, fill = NA)
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a look at [tibbletime](https://github.com/business-science/tibbletime).

Assuming your data frame is named `mydata` and the `Date` column is a character: first convert the `Date`, then convert to a time-aware tibble:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibbletime)

mydata <- mydata %>% 
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, "%m/%d/%Y")) %>% 
  as_tbl_time(index = Date)
```

Now you can define functions for rolling mean and sd:

```
mean_5 <- rollify(mean, window = 5) 
sd_5   <- rollify(sd,   window = 5) 

mydata %>% 
  mutate(rolling_mean = mean_5(Dispersion),
         rolling_std  = sd_5(Dispersion))

# A time tibble: 30 x 5
# Index: Date
   Identifier Date       Dispersion rolling_mean rolling_std
        <int> <date>          <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
 1       1000 2018-02-15      0.39        NA          NA    
 2       1000 2018-02-16      0.664       NA          NA    
 3       1000 2018-02-17      0.526       NA          NA    
 4       1000 2018-02-18      0.933       NA          NA    
 5       1000 2018-02-19      0.009        0.504       0.342
 6       1000 2018-02-20      0.987        0.624       0.393
 7       1000 2018-02-21      0.517        0.594       0.394
 8       1000 2018-02-22      0.641        0.617       0.393
 9       1000 2018-02-23      0.777        0.586       0.367
10       1000 2018-02-24      0.613        0.707       0.182
# ... with 20 more rows
```